# SEO: с чего начать?

Tags: seo

Прошу помощи в вопросе, в котором плохо разбираюсь.

Дело вот в чём. Хотел я немного понять принципы seo: как и с чем его вообще едят, перечитал кучу статей всяких, форумов, блогов, пересмотрел видеоуроков и просто роликов (особенно порадовала вот эта [реклама](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXhAfvA8-TI)). Ну, что-то я узнал, что-то нет, **но** нигде не нашёл систематических данных. Ну, то есть что за чем стоит делать. Я как нормальный человек подумал, надо попробовать всё, что узнал руками потрогать (ну, сайта у меня нет, который бы мне надо было продвигать, но условно хотя бы, имитируя продвижения, хотелось потрогать). И тут начинаются вопросы.

- Ну, я в курсе, что необходимо занести сайт в каталог яндекса, гугла и т.д., но как это сделать? (Некоторые пишут, что при хорошем хостинге и правильном домене сайт автоматически попадает, некоторые просто опускают эту тему), а вот как проверить, есть ли сайт в каталоге и если нету, как туда занести, нигде не нашёл.
- Потом возник вопрос следующий. Везде написано, что сайт надо продвигать на определённые слова, которые забивают в поисковиках, слышал, что существует где-то рейтинг таких запросов (и даже то, что яндекс ведёт этот рейтинг по региональному принципу), но где найти этот рейтинг? Как его посмотреть?
- Где-то вычитал, что в HTML(е) стоит указывать метатеги и многое другое оптимизировать, но как это лучше осуществлять после того, как сайт уже положил на хостинг вебмастер? Просить у него html файл, его допиливать и потом просто вставлять на хостинг вместо уже лежащего там?

Ну, и таких вопросов очень много. В связи с этим хотел бы у вас узнать, может кто-то подскажет какую-то литературу, статьи, чей-то блог, какие-то уроки, где бы это всё было достаточно понятно и систематизированно выложено.

Comment: Вам нужно сначала разобраться, как работают поисковые системы, понять, как собирать семантику, освоить работу инструментов SEO и веб-аналитики. Попробовать знания на практике и сможете самостоятельно продвигать свой проект. Также нужно разобраться как вести трафик на сайт для увеличивать потока заявок и продаж. И, наконец, нужно пошагово разобраться в тонкостях сбора семантики для сайтов, научиться выводить их в топ поиска. Вообще-то источников в инете много, но лучше пользоваться советами специалистов. Лично мне помогли статьи из [https://ipapus.com/category/seo-jenciklopedija/](https://ipapu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Каталоги Яндекс и Google. Чтобы добавить сайт в каталог Яндекс надо заполнить и отправить [форму](http://yaca.yandex.ru/add_free.xml) на странице каталога. Под каталогом Google обычно понимают dmoz.org. Там есть аналогичная форма (сейчас почему-то недоступна). Сайт может попасть в каталог и без ваших действий, но тогда это должен быть исключительно значимый сайт - такой, что мимо него не пройти, не заметив. Если редакторы добавят ваш сайт в каталог, они уведомят вас об этом. Проверить наличие сайта в каталоге просто: надо найти либо не найти его там.
- Статистика [Яндекс](http://wordstat.yandex.ru/) и [Google](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__c=1000000000&__u=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS) открыта для всех желающих: можно подбирать слова и словосочетания и смотреть их частоту в пользовательских запросах по миру и регионам.
- Либо перезаливать HTML-файл на сервер (если файл статический), либо менять из админки сайта (то есть обновляя базу данных), если сайт динамический.

Классика: [оптимизация и продвижение сайтов в поисковых системах](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6195415/) Ашманова и Иванова. Ну и полезно читать справку для вебмастеров на сайтах Яндекс и Google.

Comment: Спасибо за определённые подсказки. Особенно за книгу.

Answer (score 4):

Начинать надо сначала. Советую ознакомиться с понятием "семантическое ядро сайта" и начать с его сбора, анализа и распределения по страницам. Таким образом Вы построите правильную структуру сайта.

Answer (score 0):

1. Каталог Яндекса закрыт на примем новых заявок, а DMOZ уже несколько
   лет не работает.
   https://webmaster.yandex.ru/blog/katalog-prekraschaet-priem-zayavok

   https://vc.ru/flood/22255-dmoz-closed
2. Вордстат как не менялся последние годы, так и не меняется. В итоге морально устарел. Гугл-тренды дают относительные данные как и
       раньше.
3. Книг хороших практически нет. В частности книгу Ашманова сложно считать хорошим актуальным мануалом, так как это окаменелости или
       палео-SEO. Для общего развития неплохая книга "SEO - искусство
       раскрутки сайтов" издательства O'Reilly.