# Какие лучшие и дешёвые сео разработки мне использовать?

Tags: html, seo

Мне нужен совет как новичку какие инструменты мне использовать для начала и что мне даст большой прирост посетителей за минимальный бюджет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/94697/301937

Comment: @Nilsan, это устаревший ответ. Ни DMOZ ни Яндекс.Каталога по состоянию на 2018 уже не существует. Спасибо.